# Find datasheet for an industrial radio remote control

Tags: rf, remote-control

At work, we have what seems like radio-based remote controls to control the window stores, the light and the temperature.  We'd like to find out what the commands are that are sent by the remote control.

I've been able to open it and take a picture of the circuitry and was looking for any tell-tale signs as to what components are.  But I'm not expert enough to recognize anything ... :-(

[image: Internal PCB]

The company name is YRIS TECHNOLOGIE (a French company apparently bought up by Schneider Electric).

How can I find out more about this remote control? Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wireless transceiver is the part labelled MRF49XA. The giveaway is the PCB trace antenna.

In the marked photo below:

- **A**: MRF49XA sub-GHz transceiver from Microchip (see the [datasheet](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MRF49XA)).
- **B**: Impedance matching network, which connects the transceiver output to the antenna.
- **C**: Base of the PCB trace antenna.
- **D**: Tip of the PCB trace antenna.

[image: PCB with markup]

The ATMEL part is the microcontroller which is running the show. If you have the resources (an oscilloscope or logic analyser) you can probe the communication lines between the microcontroller and the transceiver to determine what is being sent.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, Daniel! The speed and precision of your answer are just crazy! Thank you so much! I guess I come back soon.